# object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Below 3 models :

Model 1: Reservation

```
    @Entity
    public class Reservation  {
    
        public static final long NOT_FOUND = -1L;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        public Long id;
        
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reservation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        public List<RoomReservation> roomReservations = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Model 2: Room Reservation:

```
 public class RoomReservation extends{
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        public Long id;
    
        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "RESERVATION_ID")
        public Reservation reservation;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roomReservation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        public List<GuestDetails> guestDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Model 3 : Guest Details:

```
public class GuestDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public Long guestId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_RESERVATION_ID")
    public RoomReservation roomReservation;

    public Boolean isPrimary;

    @Transient
    public Guest guest;

}
```

The Relationship between those three are as :

**Reservation --One to Many on RESERVATION_ID--> Room Reservation --One to Many on ROOM_RESERVATION_ID--> Guest Details**

I am getting the reservation object and trying to update guest details i get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.model.GuestDetails.roomReservation -> com.model.RoomReservation
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1760)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
... 73 common frames omitted
```

**I have changed cascadeType to ALL as suggested in common question still getting the same error.Please donot make it duplicate as i have tried all the solution realated to this kind of question already asked**

Please Let me know what mistake i am doing. Thanks

**Code to save Reservation Object by changing GuestDetails:**

```
Reservation existingReservation = reservationRepository.findOne(reservationId);
Reservation reservation = reservationParser.createFromJson(reservationNode);
existingReservation.roomReservations.forEach(roomReservation -> {
                    RoomReservation updatedRoomReservation = reservation.roomReservations.stream().filter(newRoomReservation -> Objects.equals(roomReservation.id, newRoomReservation.savedReservationId)).findFirst().orElse(null);
                    if(updatedRoomReservation != null){
                        roomReservation.guestDetails = updatedRoomReservation.guestDetails;
                    }
                });
reservationRepository.save(existingReservation);
```

Comment: Please post the code that's actually doing the saving - what class type are you trying to save ?

Comment: @PaulNUK I have added code block which i am using to save.Please have a look.

Comment: @PaulNUK Hi, any Updates..?

Comment: Maybe you can post your `save()`-Method? And I guess you need to persist your changed data after the `foreach` call in reservation. Also try to add a specific cascade-type to `RoomReservation` at the `GuestDetails` and other members.

Comment: This issue used to happen when child object is null . Make sure you have mapped object both ways .

Comment: `newRoomReservation.savedReservationId`. What is this `savedReservationId` property? Cannot spot it in `RoomReservation` class posted.

Comment: @soorapadman- Thanks,That was the issue :)

Comment: Thanks everyone the issue is resolved,the null child object was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
... save the transient instance before flushing : 
    com.model.GuestDetails.roomReservation -> com.model.RoomReservation
```

This exception states clearly that `RoomReservation` contained in `GuestDetails`, does not exist in the database (and most likely it's `id` is `null`).

**In general**, you can solve this exception either by :

- Saving RoomReservation entity before saving GuestDetails
- Or making `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` (or at least `{CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}`) for `@ManyToOne` `GuestDetail-->RoomReservation`

But first, I have a couple of points to cover:

- Do not use public fields in your class, this violates [the encapsulation concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).
- While you have a bidirectional association, you can set the other side of the association in your `Setter` methods.

For your case, you should change `RoomReservation` class :

```
public class RoomReservation{

    //..... other lines of code

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roomReservation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<GuestDetails> guestDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setGuestDetails(List<GuestDetails> guestDetails) {

           this.guestDetails.clear();

           // Assuming that by passing null or empty arrays, means that you want to delete
           // all GuestDetails from this RoomReservation entity
           if (guestDetails == null || guestDetails.isEmpty()){
               return;
           }

           guestDetails.forEach(g -> g.setRoomReservation(this));
           this.guestDetails.addAll(guestDetails);
    }

    public List<GuestDetails> getGuestDetails() {
        // Expose immutable collection to outside world  
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(guestDetails);
    }

    // You may add more methods to add/remove from [guestDetails] collection
}
```

Saving the Reservation:

```
Reservation existingReservation = reservationRepository.findOne(reservationId);
Reservation reservation = reservationParser.createFromJson(reservationNode);
existingReservation.roomReservations.forEach(roomReservation -> {
                    Optional<RoomReservation> updatedRoomReservation = reservation.roomReservations.stream().filter(newRoomReservation -> Objects.equals(roomReservation.id, newRoomReservation.savedReservationId)).findFirst();
                    if(updatedRoomReservation.isPresent()){
                        // roomReservation already exists in the database, so we don't need to save it or use `Cascade` property
                        roomReservation.setGuestDetails( updatedRoomReservation.get().getGuestDetails());
                    }
                });
reservationRepository.save(existingReservation);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by incorrect transaction semantics.

If the referenced instance was not fetched in the current transaction it counts as transient.

The easiest solution is to add `@Transactional` to the method:

```java
@Transactional
public void saveReservation(...) {
    Reservation existingReservation = reservationRepository.findOne(reservationId);
    Reservation reservation = reservationParser.createFromJson(reservationNode);
    // ...
    reservationRepository.save(existingReservation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`GuestDetails`** - add the needed CasadeType:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_RESERVATION_ID")
public RoomReservation roomReservation;
```

RoomReservation - add the nedded CascadeType:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.AL)
@JoinColumn(name = "RESERVATION_ID")
public Reservation reservation;
```

And then you need to persist the data before/after using the for-each loop. Depends on you `safe()`-Method.

```
Reservation reservation = reservationParser.createFromJson(reservationNode);
entityManager.persist(reservation);
```

And then safe it afterwards. Tell me your result. Maybe directly working without changing/adding the cascadetypes.

Comment: I have tried adding cascadeType.ALL to Guest Details,and persisting object after loop still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the reservation you get from the Json. 
JPA will update the rows with the same id's.

The error you get is because the guestDetails has still a reference to the updatedRoomReservation.
If you don't want to save the whole reservation from the json you have to set the right RoomReservation.

e.g.:

```
if(updatedRoomReservation != null){
    roomReservation.guestDetails = updatedRoomReservation.guestDetails;
    guestDetails.forEach(guestDetail -> guestDetail.roomReservation = roomReservation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA 2.0 then defaults fetch type for OneToMany is LAZY. If after your lambda,  your `updatedRoomReservation` is **null** (as you set in orElse) then `existingReservation.roomReservation.guestDetails` will never be loaded and will be null.

Therefore when you save `existingReservation`, you get the error.